# How to add an action to UITextview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I want the text in the `UITextView` to change whenever a user clicks on the `UITextView`.
How can i do that programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use UITextViewDelegate.

In this method:

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
   textView.text = @"Your text";
}
```

Comment: sorry, I'm new to this whole thing. can you elaborate more?

Comment: If you post your code I would try to explain better. So I assume you have a viewController, that has a textView. Make your view controller to be a UITextViewDelegate. Then, add all the methods that are required for the delegate support. Then add textViewDidBeginEditing method, this is where your tap event will be caught. Inside of that method add the editing code, that will change the value of the textView you need.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift you can use:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
{
    textField.text = "Some text";
}
```

Check the link below also:

[UITextFieldDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldDidBeginEditing:)